# rewrite url using config.xml

Tags: xml, magento, url-rewriting

I'd created a module and the url for the same is something like:

```
http://magento.korenpub.com/designer/index/index/id/26/value/Joseph%20B.%20Soloveitchik
```

but I need to rewrite the url to

```
http://magento.korenpub.com/author/id/26/value/Joseph%20B.%20Soloveitchik
```

How can it be done with `config.xml`? I'd read this [blog](http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/magento-url-rewrite-using-config-xml-and-regular-expressions/) which describes such, but I'm unable to do it for my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd been thinking it in more complicated way but its so simple

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```